# Gem works in IRB but not Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am trying to use the Hubspot API Ruby gem located here https://github.com/HubSpot/hubspot-api-ruby#installation, but I am having issues with Ruby on Rails.

For all of my other gems, I can just simply add the gem in the Gemfile and it works within the application, but not this case and I cannot figure out why.

For example, here's what I have in my Gemfile:

```
# HubSpot API Client
gem 'hubspot-api-client'
```

I have ran `bundle install` and it installed successfully, but I still can't use that gem. If I load the gem via the `irb` console, then it works just fine.

Here's what I mean:

*Using IRB*

```
root@8af3866a29c8:/myapp# irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'hubspot-api-client'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> Hubspot
=> Hubspot
```

*Using Rails Console*

```
root@8af3866a29c8:/myapp# rails c
Running via Spring preloader in process 6589
Loading development environment (Rails 5.2.4)
irb(main):001:0> require 'hubspot-api-client'
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):1
LoadError (cannot load such file -- hubspot-api-client)
irb(main):001:0> Hubspot
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):1
NameError (uninitialized constant Hubspot)
irb(main):002:0>
```

Why does this happen and how do I fix this?

Comment: If you have it in your gemfile, unless you used `require: false` then you wont need to manually require it in your rails console.

Comment: Even with it being that way or the other way (manually requiring it), it still doesn't work, but that's a good tip I wasn't aware of. Thanks

Comment: In any case ... this seems to be a much more popular gem - https://github.com/HubspotCommunity/hubspot-ruby

Comment: Are you using other gems succesfully from Rails? Just want to make sure you're using your application's version instead of the systems, though I think this is unlikely. Maybe try `bundle exec rails c` and see if it makes a difference?

Comment: Yep. Every other gem works fine from Rails

Comment: Works in my case. It could be issue from the gem, Rails, OS. So you could try to debug by trying: older versions of 'hubspot-api-client', newer versions of Rails, or another OS.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include **gem 'hubspot-api-client'** in your Gemfile.
Rails only load the gems which are specified in your Gemfile.

Comment: That's what I did. I posted that in the original post.

Comment: Can you share you gem 'hubspot-client' version.

Comment: /usr/local/bundle/gems/hubspot-api-client-9.3.0

Comment: I have same version install in my machine. after bundle update I check on irb and rails console so it is working, only thing first time it return true but after load it return false

Comment: It's working in rails console as well? You're able to call `Hubspot` and it works?

Comment: Yes I am able to call `Hubspot` and it works!